# Check this code in Matlab. I cannot understand the way the script reads the data

Tags: matlab

```
% Set up variables --------------------------------------------------------
folder = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
if ( isempty( folder) )
    folder = pwd;
end
folder = [folder '\data'];


% =========================================================================
% EDIT THIS ===============================================================
% Make sure to fill the variables samples with the eye movement data in the
% proper colums. In blinks mark all the samples that are not good data. In
% most VOG systems it is best to remove 100 ms before and after the blink
% to remove all artifacts.
% =========================================================================
    session = 'test';
    samplerate = 500;

%     samples = [];
%     %  samples(:,1)     timestamps of the recording in miliseconds
%     %  samples(:,2)     horizontal position of the left eye in degrees
%     %  samples(:,3)     vertical position of the left eye in degrees  
%     %  samples(:,4)     horizontal position of the right eye in degrees     
%     %  samples(:,5)     vertical position of the right eye in degrees
```

I am a bit confused with this. I have found this script online, but i can't understand how to input data in a way to work. I tried with some data files but it doesn't. I attach only the part of the script which is about reading data

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a folder named `data` that lives in the same folder as the script itself. To deal with potential differences in file path separators across operating systems, I would change `folder = [folder '\data']` to `folder = fullfile(folder, 'data')`.

If you want, you could also just assign `folder` to point to wherever you would like to keep your data.